# Renaming multiple columns in a panda dataframe where by renaming it you might accidently create columns with the same name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, in python, with these headers

```
GP  2016-Dec    2017-Jan    2017-Feb    2017-Mar    2017-Apr    2017-May    2017-Jun    2017-Jul    2017-Aug    2017-Sep    2017-Oct    2017-Nov
```

and I want to change it to

```
GP     2017-Jan    2017-Feb    2017-Mar    2017-Apr    2017-May    2017-Jun    2017-Jul    2017-Aug    2017-Sep    2017-Oct    2017-Nov    2017-Dec
```

So I created an array with the date I want to replace for

```
new_date = [u'2017-Jan', u'2017-Feb', u'2017-Mar', u'2017-Apr', u'2017-May', u'2017-Jun', u'2017-Jul', u'2017-Aug', u'2017-Sep', u'2017-Oct', u'2017-Nov', u'2017-Dec']
```

and an array for the old date

```
old_date = Index([u'2016-Dec', u'2017-Jan', u'2017-Feb', u'2017-Mar', u'2017-Apr',
   u'2017-May', u'2017-Jun', u'2017-Jul', u'2017-Aug', u'2017-Sep',
   u'2017-Oct', u'2017-Nov'],
  dtype='object')
```

​and then made a cycle where it changes each column, one by one.

```
j = 0
for i in new_date:
     print old_date[j] + ' : ' + i
     df.rename(columns={old_date[j]  :  i}, inplace=True)
     j = j + 1
```

and the end result is

```
GP  2017-Dec    2017-Dec    2017-Dec    2017-Dec    2017-Dec    2017-Dec    2017-Dec    2017-Dec    2017-Dec    2017-Dec    2017-Dec    2017-Dec
```

So, the reason my cycle doesn't work is because when I rename my first column "2016-Dec" to "2017-Jan", the new dataframe will look like this

```
GP  2017-Jan    2017-Jan    2017-Feb    2017-Mar    2017-Apr    2017-May    2017-Jun    2017-Jul    2017-Aug    2017-Sep    2017-Oct    2017-Nov
```

it will have two columns that will be name "2017-Jan" and then the next cycle begin and the program will rename all the columns that are name "2017-Jan" to "2017-Feb"...and so on.

So the real problem is that I don't know how to fix it or if there is a more direct way to change all of the columns at once. Hope someone will enlight me! Thanks!

Comment: are your column names really strings (unicode) or datetimes?

Comment: They are string not datetimes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of renaming the column every time in the for loop. you could build a dict that maps old dates and new dates and then use that dict to rename. See the example below

```
old_date =[u'2016-Dec', u'2017-Jan', u'2017-Feb']
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([(1,2,3)],columns = old_date)
print df
'''
   2016-Dec  2017-Jan  2017-Feb
0         1         2         3
'''

new_date = [u'2017-Jan', u'2017-Feb', u'2017-Mar']
map_dict = {}
for o,n in zip(old_date,new_date):
    map_dict[o] = n

print map_dict
'''
{u'2016-Dec': u'2017-Jan', u'2017-Jan': u'2017-Feb', u'2017-Feb': u'2017-Mar'}
'''

df.rename(columns=map_dict, inplace=True)
print df

'''
      2017-Jan  2017-Feb  2017-Mar
0         1         2         3
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `dataframe` is called `df`, try the following:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

df.columns = [(pd.to_datetime(df.columns[i]) + relativedelta(months=1)).strftime(format="%Y-%b") for i in range(0, len(df.columns))]
```

Basically what the code does is it loops on the various elements of your column index, and with each element does the following:

1. converts your string to a `datetime`
2. adds 1 month to your `datetime`
3. converts back to a `string` in your desired format (`"%Y-%b"`)